# Tkinter : How to bind parentheses key

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, parentheses

I have a program that needs to handle whenever the user enter a parentheses. I have tried:

```
root.bind("<Shift-KP_9>")
```

But it didn't work, the same with

```
root.bind("<Shift-9>")
```

How can I bind parentheses events into Tkinter ? Please help me

Comment: You can also follow a list of tk keysysm codes - https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to overthink it. `root.bind("<(>")` will work just fine.